# Importing large number of records in json file to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, import

I just started learning to build nodejs application. I am able to figure how things work so i made decision to test my application with large test data.
I create json file with 1 million records in it.

I import data using

```
mongoimport --host 127.0.0.1 --port 27017 --collection customers --db Customer --file "path to json file mock.json" --jsonArray
```

Sample Json file is

```
[{"fname":"Theresia","lname":"Feest","email":"aileen@okeefe.name"},
{"fname":"Shannon","lname":"Bayer","email":"tristian.barrows@christiansenvandervort.com"},
{"fname":"Cora","lname":"Baumbach","email":"domenico.grimes@lesley.co.uk"},
{"fname":"Carolina","lname":"Hintz","email":"betty@romaguerasenger.us"},
{"fname":"Dovie","lname":"Bartell","email":"rogers_mayert@daniel.biz"}]
```

but it is taking too much time approx. 14 Hrs.

Please suggest any other optimized ways for the same.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884838/the-speed-of-mongoimport-while-using-jsonarray-is-very-slow) post

Comment: @KrishnaPullakandam thanks for right direction, it was really helpful. JSON array is somehow slow than json data in new line

Comment: Glad to know. mongoimport might be splitting the file to import in parallel. With array I would guess it has to put the data into buffer and load it.How much time does it take now?

Comment: earlier it was 20/sec, now it is 8k/sec to 9k/sec. :-), it was huge difference.

Answer (score 0):

Split your single json file into multiple files and then run multiple parallel mongoimport commands for each of the file.