# Splitting a larger json file into smaller files

Tags: json, jq

I have a json file that is 2.37 gb with about 2.1 million records. I wanted to use jq to go through the file and create a new file every 100000 records.

I.e

part1.json
part2.json
part3.json
part4.json
part5.json
etc

Has anyone done this with jq?

Comment: is there a problem with using the file as it is? Won't the files have to be all put back together to make a coherent object / array to be used eventually? A piece of valid JSON is always one of those two things...if you split it up every x records then you'd presumably have to split into multiple arrays...would it then still have the same meaning afterwards? Maybe it doesn't matter for your purpose, but just something to consider.

Comment: @oharr - I believe you've already asked this question at https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1712; an answer was given there, with the suggestion that if you have further questions, you should provide further details.  Please also see [mcve]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49808581/using-jq-how-can-i-split-a-very-large-json-file-into-multiple-files-each-a-spec

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using jq how can I split a very large JSON file into multiple files, each a specific quantity of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49808581/using-jq-how-can-i-split-a-very-large-json-file-into-multiple-files-each-a-spec)

Answer (score 5):

Well you could use jq in conjunction with `split` to write those files.

```
$ jq -nc --stream 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs))' large_file.json |
    split -dl 100000 -additional-suffix=.json - part
```

Comment: Does the job, with a minor correction, you have to pass `--additional-sufix`, not `-additional-suffix`, i.e with two `-` characters.