# Split a huge JSON Document into muntiple json document in Oracle

Tags: json, oracle

I have a JSON document column in Oracle DB table. The JSON column structure is as follows:

```json
{
  "C1":1.1,
  "C2":1.2,
  "C3":1.3,
  "C4":1.4,
  "C5":1.5,
  "C6":1.6
}
```

Keys are some variables and value is amount which can be very big.
Now, since the document is growing and we can have around 1000 key-value there is possibility of document exceeding 32767 bytes.
Is there a way to split this document after say 60 key-value. So, first 60 key-value in one doc, next 60 in another doc and so on..

Comment: I don't know if this can be done in Oracle itself (REGEXP has similar limitations), have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49808581/using-jq-how-can-i-split-a-very-large-json-file-into-multiple-files-each-a-spec

Comment: And why 32k is a problem? use clob for the json column instead of varchar2

Comment: I have used CLOB datatype only, we can extend the document size also but in case of huge data it would be better to split the documents

Comment: Depending on your use case, you may be better off storing the data in relational format, as it is really a very simple json.

Comment: No I can not have it in relational format because these key-value are dynamic..they could be in any number 1,2,100,1000 as many.

Comment: If you're already using a CLOB then why is the varchar2 size limit an issue at all; and *why* would it be better to split it up? You'd need to add additional data to identify related sub-documents and manipulate those as one combined document, with no obvious benefit from what you've shared so far.

Comment: The issue of size limitation may be solved by `clob` as a storage as mentioned above (while in relational DBMS it would be better to use relational structures), but you still will have a limitation on the number of JSON keys (that is either 32k or 65k)

Comment: So, you mean to say CLOB will not have any size limitations? even if number of key-value increases.